# Copy files to document library in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a document library in SharePoint. When a new file is uploaded to that library I want it to automatically get copied to a another document library as well. How can I do this?

Comment: Within the context of the C# and SharePoint tags this question makes perfect sense - voting to reopen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use an item event receiver and override the [ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx) event. [SPItemEventProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties_members.aspx) will give you a reference to the list item via the ListItem property.

There are two methods to do this (thanks to your discovery of CopyTo).

**Method 1: Use [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.copyto.aspx)**

This method copies any list item with its associated file and properties to any location in the same site collection (possibly other web applications as well but I haven't tested). SharePoint automatically maintains the link to the source item as well if you view the item's properties or use its drop-down menu. This link can be removed with [UnlinkFromCopySource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.unlinkfromcopysource.aspx).

The only trick to CopyTo is that a full URL is required for the destination location.

```
public class EventReceiverTest : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        properties.ListItem.CopyTo(
            properties.WebUrl + "/Destination/" + properties.ListItem.File.Name);
    }
}
```

**Method 2: Stream copy, manually set properties**

This method would only be necessary if you need more control over which item properties are copied or if the file's contents need to be altered.

```
public class EventReceiverTest : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPFile sourceFile = properties.ListItem.File;
        SPFile destFile;

        // Copy file from source library to destination
        using (Stream stream = sourceFile.OpenBinaryStream())
        {
            SPDocumentLibrary destLib =
                (SPDocumentLibrary) properties.ListItem.Web.Lists["Destination"];
            destFile = destLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(sourceFile.Name, stream);
            stream.Close();
        }

        // Update item properties
        SPListItem destItem = destFile.Item;
        SPListItem sourceItem = sourceFile.Item;
        destItem["Title"] = sourceItem["Title"];
        //...
        //... destItem["FieldX"] = sourceItem["FieldX"];
        //...
        destItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
    }
}
```

**Deployment**

You have various options for deployment as well. You can associate event receivers with a feature connected to a content type or list, and programmatically add them. See [this article at SharePointDevWiki](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Event+Receivers) for more details.

Comment: Make sure to not forget to copy metadata as well!!

Comment: Hi Alex, i noticedd a CopyTo method associated with the SPFile object. can I make use of this?

Comment: @raklos Answer now updated, good find! Thanks