# Copying Sharepoint "list" from one Sharepoint Server (2007) to Another Server(2010) using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I want to programatically copy List of One Sharepoint (2007) to another Sharepoint(2010).
Using Sharepoint web services.(C#)

How should i proceeed?

Regards,

Jene

Answer (score 3):

Please see: [copy list items from one list to another in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075323/copy-list-items-from-one-list-to-another-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 1):

See the link bellow it may help you

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-a-list-by-using-a-list-template-HA101782479.aspx