# exceeds the list view threshold 5000 items in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm upgrade my sp 2007 to sp 2010 and I have a form library has more then 5000 items.
Default view of form library filter items and show only 10-20 item to users.

After upgrade sp2010 All users get below error when going to form library expect site collection admins.

I think this is a permission issue but i did not find any source to solve this issue, have any idea ?

> This view cannot
>   be displayed because it exceeds the
>   list view threshold (5000 items)
>   enforced by the administrator.
>
> To view items, try selecting another view or creating a new view.
>   If you do not have sufficient
>   permissions to create views for this
>   list, ask your administrator to modify
>   the view so that it conforms to the
>   list view threshold.

Comment: Some points I would suggest to re-check: a. is the recycle bin empty? (also the site collection recycle bin) b. do you have any lookup column pointing to a list that has more items than the threshold? c. double check the indexes on your list regards,
Luca

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The setting for the list throttle

- Open the SharePoint Central
  Administration,
- go to Application
  Management --> Manage Web
  Applications
- Click to select the web application that hosts your list (eg. SharePoint - 80)
- At the Ribbon, select the General Settings and select Resource Throttling
- Then, you can see the 5000 List View Threshold limit and you can edit the value you want.
- Click OK to save it.

For addtional reading:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinaayoub/archive/2010/04/22/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-the-list-view-threshold.aspx

Comment: This solution is not recommended by Microsoft. You should be looking at Simon Rudd's solution

Comment: I upvoted Panco's and Simon's.  Simon's is good information to have, but in our situation, Panco's solution is the one that solves the problem best.

Answer (score 27):

You can increase the List View Threshold beyond the 5,000 default, but it is highly recommended that you don't, as it has performance implications. The recommended fix is to add an index to the field or fields used in the query (usually the ID field for a list or the Title field for a library).

When there is an index, that is used to retrieve the item(s); when there is no index the whole list is opened for a scan (and therefore hits the threshold). You create the index on the List (or Library) settings page.

This article is a good overview: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010377496.aspx

Comment: My current issue is because the threshold is breached it doesn't allow new indexes and it isn't applying any new filters to the views.  So it is forever stuck unless I change the threshold or remove items from the list programatically.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.please do the following it may help you:
By Default List View Threshold set at only 5,000 items this is because of Sharepoint server performance.

To Change the LVT:

1. Click SharePoint Central Administration,
2. Go to Application Management
3. Manage Web Applications
4. Select your application
5. Click General Settings at the ribbon
6. Select Resource Throttling
7. List View Threshold limit --> change the value to your need.
8. Also change the List View Threshold for Auditors and Administrators.if you are a administrator.

Click OK to save it.

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint lists V: Techniques for managing large lists](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/overview-RZ101874361.aspx?section=1) :

Tutorial By Microsoft

Level:   Advanced

Length:  40 - 50 minutes

When a SharePoint list gets large, you might see warnings such as, “This list exceeds the list view threshold,” or “Displaying the newest results below.” Find out why these warnings occur, and learn ways to configure your large list so that it still provides useful information.

After completing this course you will be able to:

- Learn what the List View Threshold is, and understand its benefits.
- Create an index so that you can see more information in a view.
- Create folders to better organize your large list.
- Use Datasheet view for fast filtering and sorting of a large list.
- Learn what the Daily Time Window for Large Queries is.
- Use Key Filters for fast filtering within Standard view.
- Sync a large list to SharePoint Workspace.
- Export a large list to Excel. Link a large list in Access.