# List View Threshold issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i created one Doc library having more than 5000 items. when i tried to display these documents in list view web part, it is showing the message like "list exceeded the limit 5000".

Pls share the solution.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093955/exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-5000-items-in-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 0):

you have to:

1- Login to Central Administration.

2- Go to Application Management -> Manage Web Applications.

3- Find General Settings button on the ribbon, click on the text "General Settings" (not the icon) and select Resource Throttling in the drop-down.

4- On the appeared page change "List View Threshold" value from 5000 to your value.

Hope that helps.