# how to copy sharepoint list data fron one list to another using c#

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Am having two list A and B now I want to copy data from list A to List B whenever a new item is added in List A using C# or sharepoint event handler.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean new item from List A also should be added to List B you can

- Use [custom workflow activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy%20List%20Item%20Extended%20Activity&referringTitle=Home)
  or
- Add OnItemAdded Event receiver to List A which creates new Item in List B

Here is code which copies list item found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215446/540694)

```
private SPListItem CopyItem(SPListItem sourceItem, string destinationListName) {
    //Copy sourceItem to destinationList
    SPList destinationList = sourceItem.Web.Lists[destinationListName];
    SPListItem targetItem = destinationList.Items.Add();
    foreach (SPField f in sourceItem.Fields) {
        //Copy all except attachments.
        if (!f.ReadOnlyField && f.InternalName != "Attachments"
            && null != sourceItem[f.InternalName])
        {
            targetItem[f.InternalName] = sourceItem[f.InternalName];
        }
    }
    //Copy attachments
    foreach (string fileName in sourceItem.Attachments) {
        SPFile file = sourceItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(sourceItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
        byte[] imageData = file.OpenBinary();
        targetItem.Attachments.Add(fileName, imageData);
    }

    return targetItem;
}
```