# How to copy SPListitem from one SPList to Another SPList

Tags: sharepoint, splistitem

I have requirement to copy items from one SPList to another,

Here is the code which is not working:

```
public void CopyList(SPList src)
{
    //Copy items from source List to Destination List
    foreach (SPListItem item in src.Items)
    {
        if(isUnique(item.UniqueId))
        {
            foreach (SPField field in src.Fields)
            {
               try
               {
                    if (!field.ReadOnlyField)
                        newDestItem = DestinationList.Items.Add();
                    newDestItem[field.Id] = item[field.Id];
                    newDestItem.Update();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   ex.ToString();
               }
            }
            //newDestItem["wrkspace"] = src.ParentWeb.Name;
            // newDestItem.Update();
        }
        DestinationList.Update();  
    }
    // DestinationList.Update();
}
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059175

Answer (score 3):

The SPListItem type has a CopyTo method that will do what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.copyto.aspx

Comment: but on the same site I read , the CopyTo method only works for SPListitems file not the object.

Comment: It applies to the list item as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.copyto.aspx

Comment: This will not work if it's a custom list. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgeorgi/archive/2008/03/06/the-splistitem-copyto-method-doesn-t-seem-to-work-on-a-custom-list.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to copy the item's attachments. Have a look at [this article](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/automatically-synchronise-sharepoint.html), part of the code has been repeated below.

```
// ** Copy the fields
foreach(SPField field in sourceItem.Fields)
{
    if (newItem.Fields.ContainsField(field.InternalName) == true && 
        field.ReadOnlyField == false && field.InternalName != "Attachments")
    {
       newItem[field.InternalName] = sourceItem[field.InternalName];
    }
}

// ** Delete any existing attachments in the target item
for (int i = newItem.Attachments.Count; i > 0; i-- )
{
    newItem.Attachments.Delete(newItem.Attachments[i-1]);
}

// ** Copy any attachments
foreach (string fileName in sourceItem.Attachments)
{
    SPFile file = sourceItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(sourceItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + 
                                                          fileName);
    byte[] imageData = file.OpenBinary();
    newItem.Attachments.Add(fileName, imageData);
}

// ** Remember where the original was copied from so we can update it in the future
newItem["_M_CopySource"] = sourceItem["FileRef"];

newItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post, [link](http://www.communardo.de/techblog/2008/01/08/sharepoint-listenelement-splistitem-in-eine-andere-liste-kopieren/). This is the best approach I found.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not call "update" on DestItem
   on every field. You only need it
   once!
2. `field.id` may be different in different lists. Use the `InternalName` property instead.
3. The exception you catch is not saved anywhere!
4. You do not have to call `DestionationList.Update`, you are not changing the destination list's settings or anything.

I modified the code to show these changes

```
public void CopyList(SPList src) 
{ 
    //Copy items from source List to Destination List 
    foreach (SPListItem item in src.Items) 
    { 
        if(isUnique(item.UniqueId)) 
        { 
          newDestItem = DestinationList.Items.Add(); 

          foreach (SPField field in src.Fields) 
          { 
             try 
              { 
                if ((!field.ReadOnlyField) && (field.InternalName!="Attachments"))
                  newDestItem[field.InternalName] = item[field.InternalName]; 
               } 
             catch (Exception ex) 
              { 
              //you should save the "ex" somewhere to see its outputs
               ex.ToString(); 
              } 
           } 
           newDestItem.Update();  //only now you call update!
        } 
       } 
      }
```

Comment: Is this possible using  ECMA Script. Currently, i my environment, I don't have VS 2010 installed and  do not have full controll on the dev.server