# cloning or copying list items in sharepoint 2007 moss

Tags: sharepoint

i have been asked to develop a feature of cloning list items in sharepoint. do you think it means the same as copying the list item to another list ?

i found a couple of places saying that this can be very tricky. and take care of versioning issues etc.

has someone already implemented this because i am not sure which method to follow out of the ones i found from google ? my list is a pretty basic one so i dont think i need versioning issues fixes etc.

please give me a link to help me out regarding this.

any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to clone the item to the same list as the parent item? Then it is not *that* tricky. See my response in this post: [How to copy SPListitem from one SPList to Another SPList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142014/how-to-copy-splistitem-from-one-splist-to-another-splist)

Comment: I needed help with using your code. i have created a new question regarding this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154294/basics-about-this-copy-list-item-code-in-sharepoint-2007-moss

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at the below location. Hope that helps

http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=107

Comment: Links to other pages or answers should be posted as a comment, unless you have some code or further explanation to add.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog post about synchronising two lists, which sounds like what you are after.

[Have a look here](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/automatically-synchronise-sharepoint.html).